Python to parsing a large text file and storing data as a Numpy 2D Array
The method I'm using works but is far too slow. Currently I'm currently not using numpy to aid in parsing, but would like to if possible.  Please let me know if this case is too complicated for numpy or if you have suggestions.  I'm not asking for final code, just suggestions. Thanks!
The data file can be organized to a 2D matrix where columns represent the digitizer channels and rows the sample values.
Each data file contain all information necessary to build the 2D matrix.  Assuming we have 5 channels, the file would contain 5 blocks of data, one for each channel, starting with channel 1 and ending with channel 5.  The channel data block contains a list of headers and the data.
An example of the header:
$ChnID=30461:0956:01:01
$Station=30461
$Samples=10800     
$Rate=1000.0    
$Time=2024:176:22:00:00.000000000
$TimeQual=0 
$BitWeight=0.000000598
$Gain=   4
$SensorVPU=0.000 
$LLA=32.987 -113.842  176.0

Important Header Information:

The last value of $ChnID is the channel number (e.g. 01).
The value of $Station    is the digitizer name (e.g. 30461).
The value of $Samples    is the number of samples in the channel (e.g. 10800).
The value of $Rate       is the sampling rate (e.g. 1000.0).

Example of Data File:
$ChnID=30461:0956:01:01
$Station=30461
$Samples=10800     
$Rate=1000.0    
$Time=2024:176:22:00:00.000000000
$TimeQual=0 
$BitWeight=0.000000598
$Gain=   4
$SensorVPU=0.000 
$LLA=32.987 -113.842  176.0
239986
240200
240147
239826
239364
238936
238559
238309
238356
238659
239086
.
.
.
$ChnID=30461:0956:01:02
$Station=30461
$Samples=10800     
$Rate=1000.0    
$Time=2024:176:22:00:00.000000000
$TimeQual=0 
$BitWeight=0.000000598
$Gain=   4
$SensorVPU=0.000 
$LLA=32.987 -113.842  176.0
-56072
-4177
117759
208797
156674
39795
-17138
-26675
-31755
-38621
-45833
-52901
-59548
-61849
-32029
70962
191732
.
.
.
$ChnID=30461:0956:01:03
$Station=30461
$Samples=10800     
$Rate=1000.0    
$Time=2024:176:22:00:00.000000000
$TimeQual=0 
$BitWeight=0.000000598
$Gain=   4
$SensorVPU=0.000 
$LLA=32.987 -113.842  176.0
100720
100840
101031
101275
101504
101652
101642
101440
101094
100704
100396
100241
.
.
.
**and so on.**

Last note:  I've seen cases where a blank lines falls between values, like:
101440
101094
100704

100396
100241

I'm currently using a class to store data for each channel (ch_obj) and manually parsing through the file to populate each channel class.
# one created for each channel in the ASC file
class ch_obj():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None       # the value of header: $Station
        self.chan_num = None   # The last value of header: $ChnID
        self.rate = None       # the value of header: $Rate
        self.data_list = []    # all channel data stored in a list


Once all ch_obj are loaded (one for each channel), I then use numpy to build the 2D array by combining the data_list from each ch_obj.

Try this approach ...
This approach avoids unnecessary list operations and makes use of numpy's efficient handling of numerical data. You should see performance improvements, especially when working with large datasets.
import numpy as np
import re

def parse_file(file_path, num_channels, num_samples):
    data_matrix = np.zeros((num_channels, num_samples))
    current_channel = -1
    current_sample = 0
    
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            # Check for headers
            if line.startswith("$ChnID"):
                channel_id = int(re.findall(r':(\d+)$', line)[0])
                current_channel = channel_id - 1  # Assuming channel IDs are 1-indexed
                current_sample = 0
            elif line.strip().isdigit() or (line.strip() and line.strip()[0] == '-'):
                # Process data line
                data_matrix[current_channel, current_sample] = int(line.strip())
                current_sample += 1
    
    return data_matrix

# -----------------------------------------

file_path = 'your_data_file.asc'
num_channels = 5
num_samples = 10800
data_matrix = parse_file(file_path, num_channels, num_samples)


Thank you for the great work!  I'm in the process of testing and will give feedback asap.

As you said, the challenge is to speed up your code. This can be done with some optimisation such as using numpy vectors. There are a few other things that can be done in order to speed up the processing.
Using a numpy array would speed things up significantly, but it depends on what you need to use the data for. But this only works if you can store everything as the same datatype. Using multiple types results in slower processing, and not leveraging the benefits of numpy. So optionally, you can create one array of strings with:
arr = np.array(["apple", "banana", "", "cherry"], dtype=str)

and numeric values with dtype as float or int (float in your case, but int would be faster)
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int)

Empty values can be filled with np.nan values.
You can stack the values with a for loop using stacked_arrays = np.stack(arrays)
Once you are done with that you can slice the arrays like:
stations = stacked_arrays[0]

In regards to the other methods of speeding up the code in general: if you are using the data to find the right items, I would recommend creating a generator. If you have to process all data, I would recommend using multithreading if possible.
Just remember, premature optimisation is the root of all evil. It may prevent later optimisation, or at least make it very difficult.

Thank you for the great work!  I'm in the process of testing and will give feedback asap.

If you don't want to see code stop reading now; I got into this and wrote some anyway, as it would be a good learning example for others.
This code assumes a fixed-sized header of consistent format, that $Samples determines the number of lines of data (including the empty values), and that zeroes should be used for empty lines. These data values look like ints; not sure if you want them to be ints, if you want to use np.NaN as suggested in another answer, you will have to make them floats. If you want a two-dimension array of channels that's left as an exercise to the reader; I don't think numpy arrays hold metadata very well, and you only have five channels, so a list isn't a big performance loss.
import numpy as np
import re

from itertools import islice

class ChObj():
    def __init__(self, file: io.TextIO, match: re.Match):
        chan_num, name, samples, rate, *_ = match.groups()
        self.chan_num, self.name, self.rate = int(chan_num), int(name), float(rate)
        self.data_list = np.fromiter(islice((0 if line=='\n' else int(line) for line in file), int(samples)), dtype=int)
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        s = ''
        s += f'Channel Number: {self.chan_num}\n'
        s += f'Name: {self.name}\n'
        s += f'Rate: {self.rate}\n'
        s += f'Data: {str(self.data_list)}\n'
        return s

pattern = r"""\$ChnID=.*:(\d+)
\$Station=(\d+)
\$Samples=(\d+)
\$Rate=([0-9.]+)
\$Time=(.*)
\$TimeQual=(\d+)
\$BitWeight=([-0-9.]+)
\$Gain= *(\d+)
\$SensorVPU=([-0-9.]+)
\$LLA=([-0-9.]+) +([-0-9.]+) +([-0-9.]+)
"""

readings = []
with open('/tmp/chan.txt', 'r') as file:
    while file:
        header = ''.join(islice(file, pattern.count('\n')))
        match = re.search(pattern, header)
        if match is None:
            break
        readings.append(ChObj(file, match))

First, let's look at the parsing. This uses regular expressions to parse the header, as suggested by others. pattern holds the regular expression pattern of the header for parsing. The number of lines in the pattern (pattern.count('\n')) is used to determine the header length. file in a Boolean context evaluates as False until EOF. We use islice to form an iterator of the header lines from file, and join it together into one string (i.e. we grab the next N lines of the file). We match the regular expression, and quit if it doesn't match. We instantiate the channel object ChObj, passing it the file (so it can continue with the data) and the match object, appending the instantiated object to the list of channel readings.
For the Channel Object (I've changed it to ChObj as this is the style preferred for classes in Python), we divvy up the first four elements of the match, ignoring the remainder (you can add assignments if you wish; use *lla at the end if you want an array of $LLA). We convert the strings to numbers (as they are parsed as strings) and store them. Then we construct a numpy array using fromiter (as suggested in other answers). We use a generator expression to obtain the next samples lines, changing blank lines to 0 as we do. This expression is more efficient than a list because it processes one-by-one, "on-the-fly". The array is built an assigned. Then we just have a __str__ method to be able to print it out (optional).
For the data:
$ChnID=30461:0956:01:01
$Station=30461
$Samples=10
$Rate=1000.0
$Time=2024:176:22:00:00.000000000
$TimeQual=0
$BitWeight=0.000000598
$Gain=   4
$SensorVPU=0.000
$LLA=32.987 -113.842  176.0
1
2
3
4
5

7
8
9
0
$ChnID=30461:0956:01:02
$Station=30461
$Samples=11
$Rate=1000.0
$Time=2024:176:22:00:00.000000000
$TimeQual=0
$BitWeight=0.000000598
$Gain=   4
$SensorVPU=0.000
$LLA=32.987 -113.842  176.0
11
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1

If we run this we get:
>>> print(*readings, sep='')
Channel Number: 1
Name: 30461
Rate: 1000.0
Data: [1 2 3 4 5 0 7 8 9 0]
Channel Number: 2
Name: 30461
Rate: 1000.0
Data: [11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1]


Thank you for the great work!  I'm in the process of testing and will give feedback asap.

I'm having an issue compiling due to the TextIO in the class.  I added import io.

my python version in VS Code is 3.10.12

The exact error:  Exception has occurred: AttributeError
TextIO, File "C:\projects\parse_test\adt_parse.py", line 32, in ChObj
def init(self, file: io.TextIO, match: re.Match):
File "C:\projects\parse_test\adt_parse.py", line 31, in 
class ChObj():, AttributeError: TextIO
